# Retrieve document template type from SPList

Tags: c#, sharepoint

When working in SharePoint I am creating a custom SPList using the following method:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms414161(v=office.15).aspx):

```
public virtual Guid Add(
    string title,
    string description,
    string url,
    string featureId,
    int templateType,
    string docTemplateType,
    SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions quickLaunchOptions
)
```

The docTemplateType is passed to declare the document template type. Is it possible to retrieve the document template type from an existing SPList? This can be useful i.e. when copying a list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SPList.BaseTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate(v=office.15).aspx) to get the list definition type on which the list is based, for example:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(<list title>);
SPListTemplateType templateType = list.BaseTemplate;
int templateTypeId = (int) templateType;
```

### How to get Document Template associated with List

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(<list title>);

var docTemplate = web.ListTemplates.OfType<SPListTemplate>()
                                   .FirstOrDefault(lt => lt.Type == list.BaseTemplate); 

Console.WriteLine(docTemplate.DocumentTemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this will return the template of the list itself (i.e. document library, discussion board etc.), and not the document template list.

Comment: The answer has been updated, see the section: How to get Document Template associated with List